# I'm trying to create a channel named like user args. [DISCORD.JS V12]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It just gives me an error that the function `message.guild.channels.create` does not work because it's not a correct name.

My intention is to create a command where you will be asked how the channel you want to create be named. So it's ask you this. After this you send the wanted name for the channel. Now from this the bot should name the channel.
(sorry for bad english and low coding skills, im a beginner)

```
module.exports = {
  name: "setreport",
  description: "a command to setup to send reports or bugs into a specific channel.",
  execute(message, args) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    

const cantCreate = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#f07a76')
.setDescription(`Can't create channel.`)



    const hasPerm = message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR");

    const permFail = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#f07a76')
.setDescription(`${message.author}, you don't have the permission to execute this command. Ask an Admin.`)
    
    if (!hasPerm)  {
     message.channel.send(permFail);
    }

else if (hasPerm) {
const askName = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(' #4f6abf')
.setDescription(`How should the channel be called?`)

   message.channel.send(askName);
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 10000 });
        console.log(collector)
         var array = message.content.split(' ');
array.shift();
let channelName = array.join(' ');
        collector.on('collect', message => {
         
            
            const created = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#16b47e')
.setDescription(`Channel has been created.`)
            
message.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
        type: "text", 
        permissionOverwrites: [
           {
             id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
             allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
             deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
           }
        ],
      })
      .catch(message.channel.send(cantCreate))
  
        })

}
else {
  message.channel.send(created)
}



       }
        }
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(channelName);` and see what the console says?

Comment: Ok, i will try.

Comment: it says it is undefined. Yeah, that's the problem :/ I think the bot doesn't know the arguments of which message it should use. But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Why are you doing `args.slice(0)`?

Comment: I copy pasted the arguments part because I'm not good enough to code it by myself. Hm :/

Comment: I am using: 
```var array = message.content.split(' ');
array.shift();
let channelName = array.join(' ');```
right now but still got the same error

Comment: Is your message collector working properly? What does the `console.log(collector);` say?

Comment: It seems like the code you posted on here seems to be a little scrambled as well. The collector should be returning a `message` object and only then you can take the content and set it as your `array`.

Comment: the collector works. But how would you change the code?

Comment: omg yeeeees i fixed it by myself. I have removed the `array.shift`. But how can I send my embed that it works when it works and my error embed if it doesnt? Cause it sends the error message

Comment: I'd try a `then()` method. Add it to your code like the `catch()` method but inside the method write `message.channel.send(created)` instead and remove that `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `message` object currently refers to the original message posted by the user. You're not declaring it otherwise, especially seeing as you're not waiting for a message to be collected before defining a new definition / variable for your new channel's name.

**NOTE:** In the following code I will be using `awaitMessages()` (Message Collector but promise dependent), as I see it more fitting for this case (Seeing as you're more than likely not hoping for it to be asynchronous) and could clean up the code a little bit.

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
let name // This variable will later be used to define our channel's name using the user's input.

// Starting our collector below:
try {
  const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
  })
  name = collected.first().content /* Getting the collected message and declaring it as the variable 'name' */
} catch (err) { console.error(err) }

await message.guild.channels.create(name, { ... })
```